# Help needed with stairs!

Tags: stairs

Looking for help with stairs.
We are in the process of adding a second level. The contractor is a complete (censored), and this has been dragging on for 2 years now.
There's been a temporary wall up separating the staircase and our living room, so we never quite noticed this. I just now realized that there is only about 30 in between the edge of the staircase and the wall of the living room/exterior wall; meaning once the railings are on the staircase, it's impossible to carry anything up the stairs and makes it an odd maneuver when you come into the front door to get into the living room.
I asked if two steps could be moved to form a right angle, but the response was, The head room won't allow it". Basically saying he won't do anything.
Any ideas on what can be done with the stairs? Thanks.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Read your contract and/or get a second opinion.  The picture does not show enough

Comment: I added another picture link.

Comment: Is that a temporary stair position till the side wall gets finish?  It does seem like a poor position for the stairs and door.  The space between the wall and stairs looks like maybe a foot or 18 inches, so almost wasted space.  What do the plans say about final stair position?

Comment: Was it built according to plan?

Comment: I do not have the original plans.  The clearance from door to stairs is 36", which is code.  These are the permanent stairs.  The contractor said this was the best place for stair placement originally, but now realize the practicality is terrible.  I

Comment: Also the wall in the picture is just temporary.  The living room is on the other side.

Comment: If you are referring to  making the bottom steps a set of "winders" it will take up more room at the door. It will change the path direction coming to the steps, but the way the treads have to fan out to make the 90 degree turn you suggest, brings the wider parts of the treads closer to the door. Or adding a landing may take up even more.

Comment: What does it look like at the top of the stairs? Please provide some more pictures? Can the stairs get pushed back? Can the treads be shortened any? Also, what is your location? Washington state requires a minimum of 18" at a landing and swing of a door. *"Door swing must not reduce the effective standing area on the landing to less than eighteen inches (45.72 cm) in depth."*

Comment: There is no room to push the stairs back.  Is it possible to make the steps steeper?  I added a full picture of the stairs up to the top.

Comment: It is possible, it is also possible to add a midspan landing and potentially turn them into the living space behind the temp wall as long as they don't impede things there as well.  What is your location, try looking up stair codes for your area.  If this is permitted work, call an inspector and address your concerns with him/her and see if they require any adjustments before final.

Comment: I'm in NJ.  Would the middle landing require more of the ceiling cut out for headroom?

Comment: Half way up the stairs it needs to turn to the right and you lose half of your living room. *Was it built according to plan?* not an approved one if the landing isn't 36". "The head room won't allow it" w/o making structural changes to the house. But that doesn't matter because it needs to go 6" back, and *six feet further going right*, taking up head room in the living room. Take the stupid wall down and it'll be obvious; you have to tear *all of that* out anyway.

Comment: Front door opens to a stair case: it should be like four or five feet, not the required minimum of three. Say goodbye to your living room.